# Datatype Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following Query

```
select distinct pincode as Pincode,CAST(Date_val as DATE) as Date,
SUM(cast(megh_38 as int)) as 'Postage Realized in Cash',
SUM(cast(megh_39 as int)) as 'MO Commission',
from dbo.arrow_dtp_upg
group by pincode,Date_Val
```

but I am getting an error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '82.25' to data type int."

Am I using a wrong data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "82.25" represents a float (or a decimal) not an int, so use `cast(megh_38 as float)` if you need a float.

If you require the integer part only then use  `floor(cast(megh_38 as float))`.

Comment: thanks for answering i tried using float but i am getting 
'Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.' as error.

Comment: one of your values is NULL.  If you want to treat this as zero, then use 'coalesce(floor(cast(megh_38 as float)), 0)'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
cast(megh_38 as decimal(10,2))
cast(megh_39 as decimal(10,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is delimiter (dot vs comma). 
Questions - why you prefer  nvarchar for store float or int values? Maybe decimal or float is better solution?